# Integral $\int x^2\sqrt{1-x^2} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, solution-verification

I tried to solve the integral $$\int x^2\sqrt{1-x^2} dx.$$
(I know there are already solutions here on MSE but I need some help to find my error)

---

Substituting $x(y):=\cos(y)$ and using trigonometirc rules yields:
$$\int \cos^2(y)\sqrt{1-\cos(y)^2}(-1)\sin(y) dy= (-1)\int \cos^2(y)\sin^2(y) dy\\= \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)\int \sin^2(2y)dy=\left(-\frac{1}{4\cdot 2}\right)\int 2\sin^2(2y)dy.$$

Then substituting again, $z(y):=2y$:
$$
\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)\int \sin^2(z)dz= \left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}z-\frac{1}{2}\sin(z)\cos(z)\right).$$
Resubstitution yields:

$$
\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(\frac{1}{2}z-\frac{1}{2}\sin(z)\cos(z)\right)= \left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(y-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2y)\cos(2y)\right) = \left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(\arccos(x)-\frac{1}{2}\sin(2\arccos(x))\cos(2\arccos(x))\right)=\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(\arccos(x)+\sin(\arccos(x))x\left(1-2x^2\right)\right)=
\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(\arccos(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}x\left(1-2x^2\right)\right).
$$

---

The result resembles the offical solution $\left(\text{which is }\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(\arcsin(x)-\sqrt{1-x^2}x\left(1-2x^2\right)\right)\right)$ except that mine has $\arccos(x)$ instead of $\arcsin(x)$ and the "$-$" sign is flipped. If I perform the substitution $x(y):=\sin(y)$. Then I arrive at the official soultion.

After revising my solution several times I have no idea where my mistake is? Maybe someone else sees it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your answer. All you need is to note that $$\arcsin x +\arccos x=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$ So with the integration constant, $\frac{\pi}{2}$ can be absorbed. The simplest way you could have checked your answer is by taking the derivative of your answer :-)

Comment: The old "off by a constant" problem.   Same thing happens when you integrate $\sin x \cos x$,  you can get 3 answers that appear different but are all the same up to a constant

Comment: @AnuragA thanks I really hate integrals that involve trigonometric functions  :D :D

Answer (score 1):

Anurag A seems to have answered your question in the comments: for all $x\in[-1,1]$,
$$
\arccos(x)+\arcsin(x)=\frac{\pi}{2} \, ,
$$
and so your solution is identical to the official one. For completeness, I will prove the above identity. Suppose that the number $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ satisfies $\cos\theta=x$. By definition, this means that $\theta=\arccos(x)$. Trigonometric identities tell us that $\sin(\pi/2-\theta)=x$. Since $\left(\pi/2-\theta\right)\in[-\pi/2,\pi/2]$, we  get that $\arcsin(x)=\pi/2-\theta$. Hence,
$$
\arccos(x)+\arcsin(x)=\theta+\left(\frac{\pi}{2}-\theta\right)=\frac{\pi}{2} \, .
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(\arccos(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}x\left(1-2x^2\right)\right)+C\\=\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)\left(\frac{\pi}2-\arcsin(x)+\sqrt{1-x^2}x\left(1-2x^2\right)\right)+C\\=-\frac{\pi}{16}+\frac{\arcsin(x)}{8}-\frac{1}{8}\sqrt{1-x^2}x(1-2x^2)+C\\=\frac18\left(\arcsin(x)-\sqrt{1-x^2}x(1-2x^2)\right)+C_1$$